# Substring/Find last occurence of "/" and output everything to the right of it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I would like to apply some type of formula that will find the last occurence of a forward slash character (/) and then output everything to the Right of it. Below is an example:

```
/shared/Custom/Conversion_Reports/Supplier Address/Supplier Address Rejection.xdo
```

In this example the last slash is the 5th one above (going from left to right), so I would want to output everything to the Right of it, which would be:
**Supplier Address Rejection.xdo**

The folder names are all variable in length and the number of folders (slashes) also varies, so thats why I need to use some type of Find function, but I do not know how to find the last occurence of a specific character. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try: `=TEXTAFTER(B2,"/",-1)`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thank you! That works great and is easier to apply then using something like: `=RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/","@",LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",""))),1))`

Comment: You don't need to use a `FIND()` function, only `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",REPT(" ",100)),100))` this works great for any version at least Excel 2010+ onwards. Try!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thanks again for the quick response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TEXTAFTER()` Function:

```
=TEXTAFTER(B2,"/",-1)
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B5`

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

---

Or, Formula used in cell `B6`

```
=FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b[last()]")
```

---

Comment: Thank you! That works great and is easier to apply then using something like: `=RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/","@",LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",""))),1))`

Comment: @Nick just updated the answer, please refer.

Answer (score -1):

I should have mentioned that this function has to be in a VBA module, where it can be called from a worksheet. I assumed that was obvious, but I should never assume anything is obvious.

In the specific case of extracting a filename from a path, a simple solution is a `FileSystemObject`. In the VBA editor, set a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (Tools/References) to make it available. Given your input path, the following function returns "Supplier Address Rejection.xdo"

For a generic solution (the last instance of any arbitrary character), or to eliminate the need for VBA, you'll need something like the other solutions offered.

```
Function FileNameFind(strName As String)
    Dim fsoFiles As FileSystemObject
    
    Set fsoFiles = New FileSystemObject
    
    FileNameFind = fsoFiles.GetFileName(strName)

    Set fsoFiles = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

textafter (A1,"/")   does not work. I get a "N/A" Neither does backslash.   If I search for any other character it works